# Can't build Cython code even with correct Visual C++ Build Tools installed

Tags: python, visual-c++, cython, cythonize

I've been trying to build a basic test file with Cython, but I keep getting `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`.

I have a setup.py file:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name='testich',
  ext_modules=cythonize("lmao.py"),
  )
```

and I've been attempting to build it both with `setup.py build_ext --inplace` and `cythonize -i lmao.py`, but they both yield the same error.

I have tried [nefedor's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553226/20203839), but it hasn't worked for me. I've tried both the latest 2022 build tools and the 2019 build tools for my python version (having only one installed at a time), installing on my C: and D: drives, with no luck. I made sure C++ build tools were checked when installing.

I'm using Python 3.8.10 and Cython 3.0.0a11, and the latest version of setuptools

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by typing the command:

```
SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

before building. Both `setup.py build_ext --inplace` and `cythonize -i` now work.

You will have to change the vcvarsall path/processor type in the command if your build tools install location/processor type are not the same.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73869315/20203839 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/419525/microsoft-visual-c-140-or-greater-is-required.html for showing me the solution, even though the Microsoft questions page mentions Anaconda it works fine with CPython.